# onClick function not working when written inside input tag in php

Tags: javascript, onclick

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" id=\"csubmit\" value=\"SUBMIT\" onClick=\"<script type='text/javascript'>ajax_post();</script>\">";
```

> when I click the csubmit button ajax_post method is not called, no alert is given and data is not getting inserted inside database which is done inside comments.php

```
<script>
function ajax_post(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    alert("button clicked");
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "comments.php";
    var bid='<?php echo $b; ?>';
    var userid='<?php echo $userid; ?>';
    var cm = document.getElementById("latest_comment").value;
    var vars = "your_comment="+cm+"&bookid="+bid+"&uid="+userid;
    hr.open("POST", url, true);
    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var return_data = hr.responseText;
            document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = return_data;
        }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Get rid of the script tag inside the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: I removed the script tag but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Replace with

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" id=\"csubmit\" value=\"SUBMIT\" onClick=\"ajax_post()\">";
```

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your file structure? (the script is not loaded). Does the console in the browser give any output?

Comment: when I load the page it gives an error  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" on line 13 which is "var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();" and when I click the button it gives another error "Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax_post is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (book_3.php.php:123)"

Comment: @SATYAMSAREEN You could **eventually** tell us the error if you want help from us...
Right now nobody can really help you because we cant actually see what you see

Comment: @SATYAMSAREEN try commenting out everything in the function except the alert part. than try again - if it alerts the out-commented code is wrong. if not - you have bad file structure or something like that

Comment: when I commented everything except alert, alert was raised so can you tell where code is wrong inside ajax_post() , It seemed fine to me